# Guides for programming CDFs

Tags: programming, output-formatting, cdf-format, slideshows

Are there any tutorials for programming high-quality CDFs, like the interactive calculus textbook [presented](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/uses-examples/textbooks.html) at wolfram.com?

*Mathematica*'s Help is extremely impressive but it really does not help much when it comes to low-level programming of the nicely typesetted documents. For example, after quite a long time I still sometimes stumble upon the output like

> Consider the equation `Cell[BoxData[FormBox[(…), TraditionalForm]]]`. The right side is…

The question might seem unsuitable but I don't think it would be productive to ask questions about the various properties of `Cell`, `TextCell`, `TextData`, etc. instead, because the problem is clearly not that local. Creating practical and good-looking interactive documents involves the use of pretty special techniques, like defining different paragraph styles, setting in-document links, making layout independent of screen resolution and magnification, and so on—maybe even manual kerning presets. Some tasks (like printing inline equations, as in the example above) are so common that there must be a solid number of convenient solutions. I'm still not aware of any tutorial aimed at discussing these particular issues. And I am probably not the only one who is interested.

Answer (score 6):

I have learned a lot from [Wolfram Training: Computable Document Format (CDF) Courses](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/cdf/).

And for a more advanced example from [Wolfram Software Development Training Course: Developing Enterprise-Class Web Applications](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/dev013.html).

For all these videos you can download the notebook to study the code.

Comment: Thanks. :-) (Pity it's video, though.)